# Activar Botón en un determinado tiempo asp c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hola amigos una consulta no se si se podra estoy realizando un sistema de gastos por periodo mensuales tengo que pagar cierto agua, luz, etc.
Estoy realizando en programacion 3 capas c# con asp.net y **BD SQL SERVER**

como la imagen :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Practicamente todo funciona bien.
El boton culminar cuando presionan se inactiva el boton pagar y todo lo que yo quiero esque cada inicio de cada mes el boton pagar se active automaticamente.
el boton Pagar. Pero cuando actualizo la pagina esta todo a su normalidad y quiero que quede enabled hasta el otro mes del 1 y sea ya activo el boton

**El codigo de mi Boton culminar es el siguiente:**

**CapaDatos**

```
 public void CerrarMes()
        {
            using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                con2.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("CerrarMes", con2))
                {
                    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();


                }
            }
        }
```

**Capa Negocio**

```
  public void CerrarMes()
         {
             D_Monto CerrarMes = new D_Monto();
             CerrarMes.CerrarMes();
         }
```

**Capa Presentacion**

```
protected void btnConcluir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            N_Monto CerrarMes = new N_Monto();
            CerrarMes.CerrarMes();

            btnPagar.Enabled = false;
            dpPagar.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Comment: Lo resolves en el Page_Load y ya btnPager.Visible = EsMesAbierto();

Comment: @kblok muchas gracias si pondrias un ejemplo como respuesta ayudarias a la comunidad.

Comment: Dale, ahi lo creo

Comment: ahi creé la respuesta, si te parece correcta la podes aceptar? gracias

Answer (score 1):

Así como tienes el método (y el procedure) `CerrarMes` yo crearía un método (y procedure) que sea `MesAbierto` que retorne un bool.

Entonces vos en el Page_PreRender podrías hacer

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnPagar.Enabled = dpPagar.Enabled = BSLogic.MesAbierto();
}
```

Al hacerlo en el Page_PreRender no tienes que hacer en btnConcluir_Click porque el PreRender se va a ejecutar después del click.

Comment: +1. Recomendacion siempre util y bueno conocer ["El ciclo de vida de una pagina ASP.NET"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms178472) ya que en algunos de estos estados es donde debemos manipular los controles de las paginas (crear dinamicamente, estados, etc)

Comment: @JoseA.Fernandez Muchas gracias por la recomendacion excelente aporte siempre lo tomare en cuenta.